# Error in web scraping in R from wikipedia

Tags: r, web-scraping

Im having trouble web scraping information from wikipedia and get the following error message:

> Error in if (length(p) > 1 & maxp * n != sum(unlist(nrows)) & maxp * n !=  :
>
> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Not sure how to fix this problem, please help me out

```
url <- 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies'
wiki <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes('table') %>% html_table(fill = TRUE)

names(wiki[[1]])
```

Output error:

```
Error in if (length(p) > 1 & maxp * n != sum(unlist(nrows)) & maxp * n !=  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the big table you can use its id. Id should be the fastest selector method for an element

```
require(rvest)
r <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies") %>%
  html_nodes("#constituents") %>% 
  html_table()
print(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there are two tables on this webpage and you shoudl specify which one you want to scrape. Let's assume you want the first one you could do something like:

```
read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes('table') %>% 
  `[[`(1) %>% ## extract first table
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
```